# Qrcode generator using Vcard in intellij java .Error "Non static method toString() can not be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

```
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import org.apache.commons.*; 
import sun.misc.IOUtils; 
import sun.nio.ch.IOUtil;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.*;

class HtmlWriter {    
  private final PrintWriter out;
  private final File dir;
  private int iota=1;

  public HtmlWriter(File dir) throws IOException {
  this.dir = dir;
  this.out = new PrintWriter(new File(dir,"out.html"));

  InputStream x = HtmlWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("/badges.html");

 // out.println(IOUtils.toString(HtmlWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("/badges.html")));

   System.out.print(IOUtils.toString(HtmlWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("/badges.html")));

  }
  public void add(String firstName, String lastName, String company, String email, String tel) throws IOException,       WriterException {
  VCardBuilder vc = new VCardBuilder();
  vc.with("N",firstName+" "+lastName)
          .with("ORG", company)
          .with("TEL", tel)
          .with("EMAIL", email);
  System.out.println(vc.toString());

  vc.writeQRCode(new File(dir,String.format("qr%04d.png",iota)));

  out.printf(
          "<div class='badge'>\n" +
                  "    <img class='qrcode' src='qr%04d.png'>\n" +
                  "    <div class='cblogo'></div>\n"+
                  "    <div class='firstName'>%s</div>\n" +
                  "    <div class='lastName'>%s</div>\n" +
                  "    <div class='company'>%s</div>\n" +
                  "</div>\n", iota, firstName, lastName, company
  );
  iota++;    }
  public void close() {
  out.println("</body></html>");
  out.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Voting to reopen, the problem described here is caused by importing the wrong class, not the usual kind of reference from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `sun.misc.IOUtils`, but you probably wanted `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`. Apache IOUtils has [the `toString()` method you want.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream))

To use it in a maven project, include the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the jar-file from project homepage: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: Importing org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils is giving the "Can not resolve symbol" error

Comment: Well, do you have the required libraries in your classpath?